# difference of Usage of MessagingException and ErrorMessage in spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I have to analyze a  spring integration piece of code  given below :

```
<int:channel id="errorChannel" />

<int:exception-type-router input-channel="errorChannel"
    default-output-channel="otherError">

    <int:mapping
        exception-type="MessageRejectedException"
        channel="mreError" />
</int:exception-type-router>


 <int:channel id="otherError" />
<int:transformer input-channel="otherError"
    ref="otherExceptionTransformer" output-channel="errors" />
<bean id="otherExceptionTransformer"
    class="OtherExceptionTransformer">
</bean>

<int:channel id="mreError" />
<int:transformer input-channel="mreError"
    ref="mreExceptionTransformer" output-channel="errors" />
<bean id="mreExceptionTransformer"
    class="MessageRejectedExceptionTransformer">
</bean>

<int:channel id="errors"/>

<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="errors"
        connection-factory="connectionFactory" destination-      
                          name="${myQueue.inbound.comp2}"/>
```

MessageRejectedExceptionTransformer takes as input as MessagingException object , however OtherExceptionTransformer takes  ErrorMessage object as input.

Till now what I have understood is MessagingException contains the failedMessage and the cause of the exception,
whereas The ErrorMessage should contain the Message type.

Now , my main point of worry is , I am not understanding in which scenario , I won't be receiving MessagingException object .

I have tried to throw nullPointerException and IllegalArgumentException from my code , and spring processed both as Messaging Exception Only. So I am wondering when that otherError channel would receive a message.

Does anyone have a view on this?

Answer (score 2):

The `ErrorMessage` has a payload of `MessagingException` which has two properties: `failedMessage` and `cause` (the original exception).

If a consumer (e.g. transformer) has an argument of `MessagingException`, the framework unwraps the payload from the message and invokes it. If the consumer takes a message (or `ErrorMessage`) it is invoked with the raw message.

Your router specifically routes on a `MessageRejectedException`, which is a subclass of `MessagingException`.

If any other `MessagingException` is thrown, the other route will be taken.